# Error dereferencing pointer after passing derived pointer to base pointer type

Tags: c++

I have a base class:

```
class IScreen {
public:
  virtual ~IScreen();

  virtual void onEnter() = 0;
};
```

And a derived class

```
class ScreenStandby : public IScreen {
public:
  ScreenStandby(ST7565&);

  void onEnter();

private:
  ST7565& lcd;
};
```

I then have a third controller class that I want to initialize that expects a parameter of the base class from above:

```
class UIController {
public:
  UIController(IScreen* left, IScreen* right, Encoder& encoder);
 ~UIController();

  void init();

private:
  // Screen for each bay from the left, hardcoded for now
  IScreen *left, *right;
};
```

I then initialize this controller with new instances of derived classes:

```
UIController UI_CONTROLLER(
  new ScreenStandby(LCD_1), 
  new ScreenStandby(LCD_2),
  ENCODER
);
```

and it's definition

```
UIController::UIController(IScreen* left, IScreen* right, Encoder& encoder)
  : left(left), right(right)
{}
```

However when I call UI_Controller.init() which dereferences one of the derived class pointers an exception gets thrown.

```
void UIController::init() {
  this->right->onEnter(); // Error gets thrown here without ever calling onEnter.
}
```

I don't think I need a copy constructor because I'm only passing in references. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the definition of the `UIController` constructor? The destructor would also be useful, you are likely violating the rule of three/five which could make dereferencing `this->right` a use-after-free error.

Comment: @cdhowie I've updated to show this, thanks for taking interest.

Comment: And the destructor?

Comment: "An exception"? What exception? What _exactly_ happens? Present your [MCVE].

Comment: I apologize everyone attempting to help.  It turns out the problem was in my ScreenStandbye constructor. I used a member initialization list but only set the type and not the name of the argument in the constructor. This somehow created a situation where this->right->onEnter(); would error likely because "right" was not initialized correctly. Since this code was so specific to my application, maybe I should delete this question..